# Number of one to one linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functions, vector-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $F_q$ be a finite field with $q$ elements. Consider $F^2_q$ and $F^4_q$ as $F_q$ vector spaces. Calculate the number of one-to-one linear transformations $T$ : $F^2_q$ → $F^4_q$ (in terms of $q$).

From my calculations I got $(q^4-1)(q^4-q)$.
But I am not sure of it.

Can anyone help with justification also!!

Comment: How did you calculate?

Comment: I just calculated using the technique where basis elements are mapped to and using linearly independence too.

Comment: I think your answer is correct. We can choose any nonzero vector for the first column of the matrix of the linear map and any vector which is nonparallel to the first vector as the second column.